# db2 temp table "with ... as ()" Arithmetic overflow

Tags: sql, math, db2, overflow, temporary

I am using the following temporary table construct inside a user-defined function to calculate fibonacci numbers.
Unfortunately, the temp-table construct gives me an arithmetic overflow error for high values, but I don't how to change the data types the temp table is using ...

```
WITH FIB_SQL(I, RES_1, RES) AS (
    SELECT 1, 0, 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT I+1, RES, RES+RES_1 FROM FIB_SQL WHERE I < 50
)
SELECT MAX(RES) FROM FIB_SQL;
```

It works for "WHERE I < 40" but not for "WHERE I < 50"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `RES` and `RES_1` are large enough that when you sum the 2 values it results in a value that is large than the data type will store.

Assume the data types are currently integers, you can cast the data types to be bigint as follows:

```
WITH FIB_SQL(I, RES_1, RES) AS (
    SELECT 1, cast(0 as bigint), cast(1 as bigint) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT I+1, RES, cast(RES as bigint) + cast(RES_1 as bigint) FROM FIB_SQL WHERE I < 50
)
SELECT MAX(RES) FROM FIB_SQL;
```

More info about integer (The range of large integers is -2147483648 to +2147483647) http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_integer.htm

vs. bigint (The range of big integers is -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807) http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_biginteger.htm

**EDIT:**
This solution using `BIGINT` will allow you to go up to I < 92, but I < 93 will still give the arithmetic overflow error, b/c then you are outside of the range of allowed BIGINT values.

If you need to use values outside the range of `BIGINT`, then checkout the `decimal` and `decfloat` data types.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_numericdatatypes.dita

Example using the decimal data type, this allows you to go up to I < 150, which returns 9969216677189303386214405760200:

```
WITH FIB_SQL(I, RES_1, RES) AS (
    SELECT 1, CAST(0.0 AS decimal(31, 0)), CAST(1 AS decimal(31, 0))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT I+1, RES, CAST(RES +  RES_1 AS decimal(31, 0)) FROM FIB_SQL WHERE I < 150
)
SELECT MAX(RES) FROM FIB_SQL 
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 150) --in SQL Server this is needed to increase the max recursion setting, not sure if this is needed in DB2 or not.
;
```

Comment: I just fixed a typo where I forgot to cast the 0 in the anchor as a bigint as well.  Should work now.

Comment: Also, this solution will allow you to go up to I < 92, but I < 93 will still give the arithmetic overflow error, b/c then you are outside of the range of allowed BIGINT values.